Android_Auto_POI_APP_
I am developing an Android Auto application based on tutorial https://developer.android.com/codelabs/car-app-library-fundamentals#0, and even with the option to run code from unknown sources enabled in the Android Auto settings, the application does not appear unless it is connected to the Android Auto emulator. When testing it on a physical Android Auto device, the application does not show up. Why is this happening? How can I fix it?
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/car-app-library-fundamentals#0

you can read in the documentation that you can not test as developer a POI app in Android Studio, you can only test message and multimedia apps https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing?hl=es-419#unknown-sources

Okey thanks, Would you know how to create a messaging app that works correctly? I have tried to create several, but I haven't been able to get them to work properly.

I didn't try with messaging app, in advice, try first to test a pet/easy project following the documentation only to check 1 message and then try to do the same in your currently project. https://developer.android.com/training/cars/messaging
